# google spreadsheet setvalues overwrites all values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have values like so

```
a
b
c
```

i want to `setValues()` over this range with

```
d
e
f
```

result is

```
d
e
f
```

pretty simple. except what if `e` is blank?

```
d

f
```

I want to it keep the old value if it is blank like so

```
d
b
f
```

if i `setValues()` over range, it would not keep where there is a blank. Is there any way to do this without looping through the whole range and set each one individually with an `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont neex an enhancement request. Simply read the original data, merge it in-memory with the new array and do a single setValues. Cheers.

Comment: what's the shortest way to do it? can you show me a few lines of code?

Comment: Sorry but you are asking us to do the code for you which this forum is not for that.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like already logged enhancement request on the Google Issue Tracker - https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=456

Please track this request there. Other than that I don't know of a way without having to loop.

Comment: thanks for the response. not a big issue. i think you guys have bigger fish to fry.